# finding part of the text and writing to another file

Tags: java, text

I have trouble finding part of text. I tried using indexOf but it was of no help as it just copying everything over to the new file.
I want to copy distinct lines with ".com.jp" and write them to a new file
here is my code

```
if(string.indexOf(".com.jp") > -1)
{
    bufferedWriter.write(string);
    bufferedWriter.write("\t");
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Comment: Let us see more code please. Just surrounding, not package lines

Comment: String line = null;
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read the `String` URL by URL, and filter the URLs you want:

```
final Scanner scan = new Scanner(string);

scan.useDelimiter("\t");

while (scan.hasNext()) {
    final String url = scan.next();
    if (url.contains(".com.jp")) {
        bufferedWriter.write(url);
        bufferedWriter.write("\t");
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a `Scanner`, you can also `split()` the `String`:

```
while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    for (String url: string.split("\t")) {
        if(url.contains(".com.jp")) {
            bufferedWriter.write(url);
            bufferedWriter.write("\t");
            System.out.println(url);
        }
    }
    bufferedWriter.write("\n");
}
```

Comment: try using .contains but it is still copying the entire thing..
for example i having ".com.jp" and ".com.tw", ".com.tw" is still being copied

Comment: @user3402193 Can you add some sample data of what you have and what you want in the question ? Because the code I provided should filter out all the lines that doesn't contains ".com.jp" (but maybe your data is separated by tabs instead of line feeds, or something like that).

Comment: sorry if I was unclear about my question. my data is from a text file, it includes many urls with different endings such as .com.sg and .com.tw. I have to specifically get .com.jp from the text file and write it into a new text file.

Comment: @user3402193 And how are the URLs separated in the text file ? By a space ? A tabulation ? A line feed ? Something else ? Nothing ?

Comment: Im using bufferedreader instead of the scanner.. how would i change frmo there?
    String line = null;
    //bufferedreader and bufferedwriter codes here
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(string.contains(".com.jp"))
    {
        bufferedWriter.write(string);
        bufferedWriter.write("\t");
        System.out.println(string); 
    }

Comment: I don't understand your code, because you are reading `line` from your `BufferedReader`, but after that you are doing your `if` on `string`, what is `string` ? Where does it comes from ?

Comment: oh i type the wrong codes, my bad. here's the correct one.
String string = null; //bufferedreader and bufferedwriter codes here while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { if(string.contains(".com.jp")) { bufferedWriter.write(string); bufferedWriter.write("\t"); System.out.println(string); }

Answer (score 0):

Let's see, well the basic idea is this.

the `string` always was holding everything.

```
  bufferedWriter.write(string);
```

where in your code are you altering that `string` var?

You need some loops to flush out the variable when you go to the next line.

Comment: String line = null; while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

Answer (score 0):

Using java for this purpose will make it complicated. 
A simple unix comand should do it:

```
grep -i '.com.jp' filename.txt > newfile.txt
```